# Pyspark dataframe to show the latest Id

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with ids that keep changing to new ids.I want to add an extra column that shows the latest Id Of any given Id.

Example:

| new_id | old_id | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d | c | 20-01-01 |
| c | b | 15-01-01 |
| b | a | 10-01-01 |
| z | y | 23-02-01 |
| y | x | 20-01-02 |

Final dataframe

| new_id | old_id | change_date | latest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d | c | 20-01-01 | d |
| c | b | 15-01-01 | d |
| b | a | 10-01-01 | d |
| z | y | 23-02-01 | z |
| y | x | 20-01-02 | z |

I tried to do a self join on old_id and new_id but doesn't seem to work because of multiple changes.

Answer (score 0):

Define `partitionBy` on temp column and then apply **`window max function`**.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([('d','c','20-01-01'),('c','b','15-01-01'),('b','a','10-01-01')],['new_id','old_id','change_date'])
df1 = df.withColumn("temp", lit(1))
w = Window.partitionBy(col("temp")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df1.withColumn("latest", max(col("new_id")).over(w)).drop("temp").show(10,False)

#output
#+------+------+-----------+------+
#|new_id|old_id|change_date|latest|
#+------+------+-----------+------+
#|d     |c     |20-01-01   |d     |
#|c     |b     |15-01-01   |d     |
#|b     |a     |10-01-01   |d     |
#+------+------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Hi notNull thanks for your response but can you please refer to my edited question which gives a better idea on the output I need.

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs are not sequentially, you can use `FIRST` or `LAST` functions on a window as well:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Mimicking data
df_data = [
    {"new_id": "d", "old_id": "c", "change_date": "20-01-01"},
    {"new_id": "c", "old_id": "b", "change_date": "15-01-01"},
    {"new_id": "b", "old_id": "a", "change_date": "10-01-01"},
]

# Creating the mocked DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_data)

# Defining the Window function
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(F.col("change_date").desc())

df.withColumn("latest", F.first(F.col("new_id")).over(w)).show(10,False)
```

This will get the first value based on the ordering in `change_date` column

Comment: Kevin Barranco,thank you for your response but the challenge is we have multiple ids going through such changes.Like for example there is another id x going through such change and becoming z, so can't rely on using Windows partition on change_date.

Comment: I see. So you want the latest ID per `old_id`, is that right? For example, if you had the ID `c` and it changed to `d` and then to `e`, you want to get the latest one but only for that specific `c` ID? If that's the case, we can achieve this by using Window functions, we will need to change it a little bit.